# Converting an int to a 2 byte hex value in C

Tags: c, string, hex

I need to convert an int to a 2 byte hex value to store in a char array, in C. How can I do this?

Comment: the int data type is 32-bit, while a 2 byte hex value is 8-bit. If your int is > 255 it won't fit in your hex value (it will overflow). Do you mean signed/unsigned char instead of int?

Comment: @wez: int is not necessarily 32 bit. But your question is a good one, he does need to watch out for overflow.

Comment: This question looks like a homework... Is this true? If so, add "homework" tag.

Comment: @Denilson: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @MikeU, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're allowed to use library functions:

```
int x = SOME_INTEGER;
char res[5]; /* two bytes of hex = 4 characters, plus NULL terminator */

if (x <= 0xFFFF)
{
    sprintf(&res[0], "%04x", x);
}
```

Your integer may contain more than four hex digits worth of data, hence the check first.

If you're not allowed to use library functions, divide it down into nybbles manually:

```
#define TO_HEX(i) (i <= 9 ? '0' + i : 'A' - 10 + i)

int x = SOME_INTEGER;
char res[5];

if (x <= 0xFFFF)
{
    res[0] = TO_HEX(((x & 0xF000) >> 12));   
    res[1] = TO_HEX(((x & 0x0F00) >> 8));
    res[2] = TO_HEX(((x & 0x00F0) >> 4));
    res[3] = TO_HEX((x & 0x000F));
    res[4] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: From seeing other people's answers, it seems they are interpreting "two byte hex value" meaning two nybbles, each represented by one byte hex character. I took it to mean two bytes of data, each represented by two hex characters. You need to clarify which you mean!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vicky. Used it to build the function in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 4):

Figured out a quick way that I tested out and it works.

```
int value = 11;

array[0] = value >> 8;
array[1] = value & 0xff;

printf("%x%x", array[0], array[1]);
```

result is:

```
000B
```

which is 11 in hex.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming int to be 32 bits;

easiest way: just use sprintf()

```
int intval = /*your value*/
char hexval[5];
sprintf(hexval,"%0x",intval);
```

Now use hexval[0] thru hexval[3]; if you want to use it as a null-terminated string then add `hexval[4]=0;`

Comment: You'll get unpredictable results (even crash) when 0xFF < intval.

Comment: Nope. Since sprintf formats intval into a string.
So 0xFFFF (which is not the maximum value for a 32bit integer by the way) would be four F's and those wouldn't fit into hexval[3], since you also have to consider the trailing 0. You won't have to add hexval[2]=0 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

```
char s[5];  // 4 chars + '\0'
int x = 4660;
sprintf(s, "%04X", x);
```

You'll probably want to check `sprintf()` documentation. Be careful that this code is not very safe. If `x` is larger than `0xFFFF`, the final string will have more than 4 characters and won't fit. In order to make it safer, look at `snprintf()`.

Comment: if int is 11. I need the resulting 2 bytes to be 0 B which is 11 in hex.

Comment: Wrong, those two characters are half-bytes, also called nibbles. A byte (8-bit, 0-255) is composed of 2 hex chars. Thus, 2 bytes are made of 4 hex chars. Each hex char (or nibble) has 4 bits (0-15, or 0-F).

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would recommend using the `sprintf` based solutions recommended by others.  But when I wrote a tool that had to convert billions of items to hex, sprintf was too slow.  For that application I used a 256 element array, which maps bytes to strings.

This is an incomplete solution for converting 1 byte, don't forget to add bounds checking, and make sure the array is static or global, recreating it for every check would kill performance.

```
static const char hexvals[][3]= {"00", "01", "02", ... "FD", "FE", "FF"};
const char *byteStr = hexvals[number];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void intToHex(int intnumber, char *txt)
{    
    unsigned char _s4='0';
    char i=4;
    //intnumber=0xffff;

    do {
        i--;
        _s4 = (unsigned char)  ((intnumber >> i*4 ) & 0x000f);
        if(_s4<10)
            _s4=_s4+48;
        else
            _s4=_s4+55;

        *txt++= _s4;    
    } while(i);     
}
...
char text [5]={0,0,0,0,0};
...

intToHex(65534,text);
USART_Write_Text(text);
....
```

Comment: I've done a lot of benchmarking and your solution has been the fastest, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `sprintf`, I would recommend using `snprintf` instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char output[5];
    snprintf(output,5,"%04x",255);

    printf("%s\n",output);
    return 0;
}
```

Its a lot safer, and is available in pretty much every compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
void IntToHex(int value, char* buffer) {
  int a = value&16;
  int b = (value>>4)&16;
  buffer[0] = (a<10)?'0'+a:'A'-(a-10);
  buffer[1] = (b<10)?'0'+b:'A'-(b-10);
}
```

Comment: This code assumes the letters A to F occupy consecutive codepoints. This is not guaranteed by the C language.

Comment: Can you think of any implementation or encoding that doesn't have the letters consecutively?

Comment: Still a nice answer, should maybe include the Baudot code and code-UPP..

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers are great, there's just one thing I'd add: you can use sizeof to safely reserve the correct number of bytes.  Each byte can take up to two hex digits (255 -> ff), so it's two characters per byte.  In this example I add two characters for the '0x' prefix and one character for the trailing NUL.

```
int bar; 
// ...
char foo[sizeof(bar) * 2 + 3];
sprintf(foo, "0x%x", bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int hex16 = ((unsigned int) input_int) & 0xFFFF;
```

`input_int` is the number you want to convert. `hex16` will have the least significant 2 bytes of `input_int`. If you want to print it to the console, use `%x` as the format specifier instead of `%d` and it will be printed in hex format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crude way of doing it. If we can't trust the encoding of ascii values to be consecutive, we just create a mapping of hex values in char. Probably can be optimized, tidied up, and made prettier. Also assumes we only look at capture the last 32bits == 4 hex chars.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFLEN 5

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int n, i, cn;
  char c, buf[5];
  char hexmap[17] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','.'};

  for(i=0;i<BUFLEN;i++)
    buf[i]=0;

  if(argc<2)
  {
    printf("usage: %s <int>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  n = atoi(argv[1]);
  i = 0;
  printf("n: %d\n", n);

  for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    cn = (n>>4*i) & 0xF;
    c  = (cn>15) ? hexmap[16] : hexmap[cn];
    printf("cn: %d, c: %c\n", cn, c);

    buf[3-i] = (cn>15) ? hexmap[16] : hexmap[cn];
  }
  buf[4] = '\0'; // null terminate it

  printf("buf: %s\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 32 bits / 4 bits-per-hex-character = 8 characters. Not 4.

Answer (score 0):

This function works like a charm.

```
void WORD2WBYTE(BYTE WBYTE[2], WORD Value) { 
    BYTE tmpByte[2]; 
    // Converts a value from word to word byte ----
    memcpy(tmpByte, (BYTE*) & Value, 2); 
    WBYTE[1] = tmpByte[0]; 
    WBYTE[0] = tmpByte[1]; 
}
```

asumming the following:

```
typedef unsigned char   BYTE; 
typedef unsigned short  WORD;
```

Example of use:

we want to achieve this:

```
integer = 92
byte array in hex:
a[0] = 0x00;
a[1] = 0x5c;

unsigned char _byteHex[2];
WORD2WBYTE(_byteHex, 92);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this it is simple and easy to convert

```
typedef union {
    struct hex{
            unsigned  char a;
            unsigned  char b;

    }hex_da;
    short int dec_val;
}hex2dec;

hex2dec value;
value.dec_val=10;
```

Now hex value is stored in hex_da structure access it for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vicky's answer above

```
typedef unsigned    long    ulong;
typedef unsigned    char    uchar;

#define TO_HEX(i)   (i <= 9 ? '0' + i : 'A' - 10 + i)
#define max_strhex  (sizeof(ulong)*2)

public uchar
*mStrhex(uchar *p, ulong w, ulong n)
{
    ulong i = 0xF;                                  // index
    ulong mask  = i << (((sizeof(ulong)*2)-1)*4);   // max mask (32 bit ulong mask = 0xF0000000, 16 bit ulong mask = 0xF000)
    ulong shift = (w*4);                            // set up shift to isolate the highest nibble
    if(!w || w > max_strhex)                        // no bold params
        return p;                                   // do nothing for the rebel
    mask  = mask >> (max_strhex-w)*4;               // setup mask to extract hex nibbles
    for(i = 0; i < w; i++){                         // loop and add w nibbles
        shift = shift - 4;                          // hint: start mask for four bit hex is 0xF000, shift is 32, mask >> 32 is 0x0000, mask >> 28 is 0x000F.
        *p++ = TO_HEX(((n & mask) >> shift));       // isolate digit and make hex
        mask = mask >> 4;                           //
        *p = '\0';                                  // be nice to silly people
    }                                               //
    return p;                                       // point to null, allow concatenation
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For dynamic fixed length of hex

```
string makeFixedLengthHex(const int i, const int length)
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::hex << i;
    ostr << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(length) << stream.str();
    return ostr.str();
}
```

But negative you have to handle it yourself.