# convert decimal to hex, add to byte array

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, hex, decimal

I am working on some image conversion in objective C, for iOS, and having some difficulties in saving the total image size in a byte array..

I did some searching, and stackoverflow has many questions with conversion from decimal to hex, but all of them explain how to print hex value using `%x` and printf(or NSLog), which is not what I want.

I have an image with size 2500

```
int totalSize  = 2500;
```

I want to add this size to specific index in image header

```
UInt8 headerData[HEADER_SIZE];
memset(headerData, 0, HEADER_SIZE);

//2500 dec  = 9C4 hex
headerData[2]   = 0xC4;
headerData[3]   = 0x09;
headerData[4]   = 0x00;
headerData[5]   = 0x00;    //image size total 4 bytes
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085612/converting-an-int-to-a-2-byte-hex-value-in-c) thread and tried it out

```
char hexval[5];
memset(hexval, 0, 5);
if (totalSize <= 0xFFFF){
    sprintf(&hexval[0], "%0x", totalSize);
}

printf("%x %x %x %x", hexval[0], hexval[1], hexval[2], hexval[3]);
```

and it printed

```
36 36 33 32
```

which is not the correct value, or am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot put the endianness part.. I want to save in little endian format.

Note : I am adding a C tag also, since a C solution is applicable here too..

Comment: @hyde 's answer is most likely correct. If you want more info, seek for  keywords such as `endianness`,`big endian`, `little endian` on SO

Comment: More information is required.  What is the endianness of the image size when written to the header?  It's most likely the same for all of the values in the header.

Comment: @trojanfoe I edited the question. Infact hyde's original answer is working fine. I am now trying to understand how it works.

Comment: Interesting, given hyde's solution stores the image size in big endian, not little endian.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra What is the actual problem? Is it the value which gets saved, or is it just the printing part? As said in my answer, that printing part is just wrong, that `sprintf` will even cause buffer overflow if `totalSize > 0xFFFF`, and print funny value if `totalSize < 0x1000`.

Comment: @hyde no problem.. Your answer works fine.. Regarding second piece of code, I just found it from the other thread (I linked in question), which I tried but was not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Revised**: so this is not byte order issue, but here's code to properly get the byte values in little endian order, byte by byte:

```
int totalSize = 2500;

headerData[2] = totalSize >> 0 & 0xFF; // 0xC4
headerData[3] = totalSize >> 8 & 0xFF; // 0x09
headerData[4] = totalSize >> 16 & 0xFF; // 0x00
headerData[5] = totalSize >> 24 & 0xFF; // 0x00
```

---

That 2nd piece of code is just wrong though in many ways. What is it's purpose?

Do you perhaps just want this (no loops or anything):

```
printf("%04x", totalSize);
```

Or to get it to hexval C string and print that:

```
char hexval[5]; // actually, since totalSize can be > 0xFFFF, 9 would be better size
snprintf(hexval, sizeof hexval, "%04x", totalSize); // note: sizeof hexval only works if hexval is char array with static size
printf("%s", hexval);
```

Or do you *really* want the ASCII codes of individual characters, when value is printed out as hex string?

---

Hmm, also, when you say "with conversion from decimal to hex", what do you mean? Storing numeric value to a binary file (I presume your image file is binary file and not XML or something) has *nothing* to do with decimal/hexadecimal conversion. It is storing a number in memory to bytes in file, and decimal/hexadecimal does not really enter into it at all (except to print values for humans to read for debugging purposes).

Comment: OK, so the issue is endianness.  But how do you make your code portable, rather than simply reversing what is currently being used? Do you know the endianness required?

Comment: @trojanfoe Endianness is defined by image format. If it is your own format, then you can define it to be anything, as long as you define it and have writing and reading code use same format. If you write number to `char[]` buffer byte-by-byte as in this answer, then that is portable already, C `>>` and `&` operators do not depend on CPU byte order (would be pretty nasty if they did...).

Comment: Well, I am trying convert png to bmp format, and bmp has all integer values stored in little endian format.

Comment: Hoohoo.. I had big misunderstanding about how integer values are stored in memory. It seems there is no need of any conversion, as I see from your answer. your original answer is working alright.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this under iOS, which is little endian, and you want little endian order, it's as simple as:

```
*(uint32_t *)(header + 2) = totalSize;
```

If you want a cross-platform solution, then the byte-by-byte solution provided by @hyde is the way to go.